# Orient multiple traverse

Tags: node.js, orientdb

I have this graph:

[image: graph]

And I'm trying to write a query with the "SQL Syntax" of OrientDB v3.0 that start from a Client and follow the read path (the X means: *and don't have `Have` relation to the Client*).

I can get the Segments, but I don't find how to walk to the Contact.
The [docs have many examples](http://orientdb.com/docs/3.0.x/sql/SQL-Traverse.html) but only walking one path.

I have tried without success these queries:

```
SELECT FROM  (TRAVERSE out("Access").out("Contain") FROM (SELECT @rid FROM Client where myId = 30543) MAXDEPTH 1)


SELECT FROM (
    TRAVERSE out("Contain") FROM
        (TRAVERSE out("Access") FROM (SELECT @rid FROM Client where myId = 30543) MAXDEPTH 1)
    MAXDEPTH 1
)

SELECT out('Access').out("Contain") FROM Client WHERE myId = 30543
```

Do you have any info to accomplish this traverse?

I'm using the Node.js API:

```
const pool = await orient.getPool();
const session = await pool.acquire();

logger.info('Running query...');
session.command(`SELECT out('Access').out("Contain") FROM Client WHERE myId = 30543`)
  .on('data', (data) => {
    if (data.out_Contain && data.out_Contain.delegate) {
      logger.info('Segment %s contains %o Contact', data['@rid'].toString(), data.out_Contain.delegate.size);
    } else if (data['@rid']) {
      logger.info('Segment %s contains %o Contact', data['@rid'].toString(), data);
    } else {
      logger.info('Data %o', data);
    }
  })
  .on('error', (err) => {
    logger.error(err);
  })
  .on('end', () => {
    console.timeEnd('query');
    logger.info('End of the stream');
    process.emit('SIGINT');
  });

logger.debug('Registering SIGINT');
process.once('SIGINT', async () => {
  await session.close();
  await pool.close();
  await orient.stop();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`match`](http://orientdb.com/docs/3.0.x/sql/SQL-Match.html#filtering-on-record-attributes-of-connected-elements) is better for this kind of tasks.

With `SELECT`:

> In the first version, the query is more readable, but it does not use indexes, so it is less optimal in terms of execution time. The second and third use indexes if they exist, (on Person.name or City.name, both in the sub-query), but they're harder to read. Which index they use depends only on the way you write the query.

But match:

> the query executor optimizes the query for you, choosing indexes where they exist. Moreover, the query becomes more readable, especially in complex cases, such as multiple nested SELECT queries.

Here the right query:

```
SELECT EXPAND(contatti) 
    FROM ( 
      match { class: Client, as: user, where : ( myId = 30543)}
        .out('Access')
        .out('Contain'){ class:Contact, as:contatti, where: (gender= 'M')},
      NOT {as:user} -Have-> {as:contatti} 
      RETURN DISTINCT contatti LIMIT 1000
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try using this code:

```
"select out_{edgeclass}.in from (select expand(out_{edgeclass}.in) from {Vetex} where {condition})"
```

Comment: I get the same rows with this: `SELECT out_Access.in FROM Client WHERE myId = 30543`